# How to make excel like cell in javascript or Angularjs dynamically?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to make excel like cell system but dynamically, Where i have to select every cell individually. 
My desired output: [image]

If i have 2 and 10, the output will be like that(above image). 2 means 2 row and 10 means 10 columns. the 2 and 10 is from database then javascript/angularjs should make the table according to those values. The second thing is that i have to select every individual cell using javascript. For example, i want to select B7 and if i click on that cell, an alert box will be shown with the selected cell number.
In real i want to store some values regarding that cell. How can i make every cell clickable? Any suggestion? I prefer angularjs.

> Edit:

Acually i want to make Yard graphical view. Staff will select cell and input goods weight(in bootstrap modal). Then save. Next time if a cell/slot has weight before, it will be in different color(red-means the cell/slot is already filled with goods) and if he click on that cell , all details will be shown regarding to that cell like weight. Database table will store yard_id,cell_id,weiight. How can make query to get details from database to have my cell filled with color and show details if the cell has details before?

> Edit 2:

You make an object in factory to set value in cell :

```
      database[createKey({
    row: 'A',
    column: 1
  })] = 12;
```

Here row A and column 1 is red colored by default. But in real app, i will have data for some cells like:

`[{"row":"A","column":1,"weight":100},
      {"row":"A","column":2,"weight":200}
      ]`.

Then how can i set those value on specific cells and have different bg color? 
I want to use this method( loadData() ) to set color(like the one you set-red color) in the cell those have value stored in database when page load for the first time :

```
function loadData() {
    fakeHttp.get('api/weights').then(function (result) {
        $scope.weights = result.data;

        console.log(result.data)
    });
};
```

I will pass json data in result.data parameter(given above).

Comment: I updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...in real app, i will have data for some cells like:... how can i set those value on specific cells and have different bg color?

You can keep `loadData` the same and change `$scope.getWeight` to accommodate the format of the data.  This takes a dependency on lodash's [find](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#find), since that makes things more concise.  If you don't want to do that you can replace `_.find` with your own `find` method that does the same thing - I'll leave that as an exercise for you :)

http://plnkr.co/edit/b0q4qTyNjQp7J2IB7ayf?p=preview

HTML

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.0.1/lodash.js"></script>
```

JavaScript

```
$scope.getWeight = function (row, column) {
  if ($scope.weights) {
    // See if there's a record with the row and column.
    var record = _.find($scope.weights, {
      row: row,
      column: column
    });

    // Was a record found with the row and column?
    if (record) {
      // If so return its weight.
      return record.weight;
    }
  }
};
```

---

> Staff will select cell and input goods weight(in bootstrap modal). Then save. Next time if a cell/slot has weight before, it will be in different color(red-means the cell/slot is already filled with goods) and if he click on that cell , all details will be shown regarding to that cell like weight...How can make query to get details from database to have my cell filled with color and show details if the cell has details before?

I didn't completely understand, but here's roughly what you could do for the parts I did understand.  This assumes you have 3 endpoints - `GET api/weights` to get the weights; `GET api/weight` to get the weight for a single cell and `POST api/weight` to update a weight.  You'll need to replace `fakeHttp` with `$http` and the actual url's. I don't know what Yard or Yard_id is.

http://plnkr.co/edit/aAiYbChTqmAwgky0WOJ3?p=preview

```
// TODO: Replace fakeHttp with $http

var module = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

module.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModal, fakeHttp) {
  $scope.rows = [
    'A',
    'B'
  ];

  $scope.columns = [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
    6,
    7,
    8,
    9,
    10  
  ];

  $scope.select = function (row, column) {
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModal.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      resolve: {
        row: function () {
          return row;
        },
        column: function () {
          return column;
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(loadData);
  };

  $scope.getWeight = function (row, column) {
    if ($scope.weights) {
      var key = createKey({
        row: row,
        column: column
      });

      return $scope.weights[key];
    }
  };

  loadData();

  function loadData() {
    fakeHttp.get('api/weights').then(function (result) {
      $scope.weights = result.data;
    });
  };

  function createKey(data) {
    var key = {
      row: data.row,
      column: data.column
    };

    return JSON.stringify(key);
  }
});

module.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, row, column, fakeHttp, $uibModalInstance) {
  $scope.row = row;
  $scope.column = column;

  fakeHttp.get('api/weight', {
    row: row,
    column: column
  }).then(function (result) {
    $scope.weight = result.data;
  });

  $scope.save = function () {
    fakeHttp.post('api/weight', {
      row: row,
      column: column,
      weight: $scope.weight
    }).then(function () {
      $uibModalInstance.close();
    });
  };
});

module.factory('fakeHttp', function ($q) {
  var fakeHttp = {};

  var database = {};

  database[createKey({
    row: 'A',
    column: 1
  })] = 12;

  fakeHttp.get = function (url, data) {
    if (url === 'api/weight') {
      var key = createKey(data);
      return $q.when({ data: 
        database[key]
      });
    } else if (url === 'api/weights') {
      return $q.when({ data: 
        database
      });
    } else {
      alert('invalid url: ' + url);
    }
  };

  fakeHttp.post = function (url, data) {
    if (url === 'api/weight') {
      var key = createKey(data);
      database[key] = data.weight;
      return $q.when({});
    } else {
      alert('invalid url: ' + url);
    }
  };

  return fakeHttp;

 function createKey(data) {
    var key = {
      row: data.row,
      column: data.column
    };

    return JSON.stringify(key);
 }
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.2" data-semver="1.6.2" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.2" data-semver="1.6.2" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/1.3.3/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <table border="1" cellspacing="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
          <td ng-repeat="column in columns" style="width: 100px; cursor: pointer" 
            ng-style="{ background: getWeight(row, column) ? 'red' :  '' }"
            ng-click="select(row, column)">
            {{row}}{{column}}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

myModal.html

```
<div class="modal-body">
  Please enter weight for {{ row }}{{ column }}
  <input type="text" class="form-control" 
    ng-model="weight" />
  <button class="btn btn-primary"
    ng-click="save()">Save</button>
</div>
```

---

> How can i make every cell clickable?

Here's how to make every cell clickable in AngularJS.

http://plnkr.co/edit/XKa5WwjyYTugDZ744iWB?p=preview

Your question was very unclear.  I couldn't tell what you wanted, exactly.

JavaScript:

```
module.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.rows = [
    'A',
    'B'
  ];

  $scope.columns = [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
    6,
    7,
    8,
    9,
    10
  ];

  $scope.select = function(row, column) {
    if ($scope.selectedRow === row && $scope.selectedColumn === column) {
      $scope.selectedRow = undefined;
      $scope.selectedColumn = undefined;
    } else {
      $scope.selectedRow = row;
      $scope.selectedColumn = column;
    }
  };
});
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <table border="1" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
        <td ng-repeat="column in columns" style="width: 100px; cursor: pointer"
          ng-click="select(row, column)"
          ng-style="{ background: row == selectedRow && column == selectedColumn ? 'yellow' : 'none' }">
          {{row}}{{column}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <br>

  Selected (row, column): 
  <br>
  ({{selectedRow || 'undefined'}}, {{selectedColumn || 'undefined'}})
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I edited my question to make more clear.@jared

Comment: @Fawel I don't understand your edit 2.  To me, it sounds like an unrelated question.  Does it relate to the modal/the rest of your question?

Comment: yes, it was related to my question. May be i could not make you understand. But i edited my edit2 section to make you clear. See it.@jared

Comment: Ok, but $scope.weights come from loadData() anf loadData() calls a fakehttp. So, i can say that main source is fakeHttp.get method (else if). And it returns ->  `database[createKey({
      row: 'A',
      column: 1
  })] = 12;`

So, where should I attach my real api call:
`$http.get("api/getYardGraphDetails")
    .then(function (r) {
        console.log(r.data)
        $scope.dataAll=r.data
    })`
       If i make api call in Load funtion , it doesn;t work:' `$http.get("api/getYardGraphDetails").then(function (result) {
            $scope.weights = result.data;
        });`

Comment: sorry for disturbing you. I am not expert in angularjs. learning now.  i can't reuse `$scope.weights` from outside of http.get method. How can i use it in $scope.getWeigh()?`  $http.get("api/getYardGraphDetails")

        .then(function (r) {
            console.log(r.data)

            $scope.weights =r.data

        })`

Comment: @Fawel You should ask a new question.  I've answered what you originally asked.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I accepted your answer as it helped me a lot. @jared

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44351375/how-to-use-http-then-response-in-another-method-which-is-called-from-view-in-an @jared

Comment: I made a live api for you. http://famousbag.toybiaconstruction.com/api/getYardGraphDetails @jared

Comment: in the api it returns data for some cell which have weight already. You can edit your previous plunker with real api now.

Comment: If i use field like A1,B5 in database, i think it will be easy to work with. What do you think? Or i am wrong? give me your suggestion, please. @jared