# How to use $http.then response in another method which is called from view in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have view which has a function inside a table td to check whether the td has data stored in database. If td has data, it will red colored:

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
            <td ng-repeat="column in columns" style="width: 100px; cursor: pointer"
                ng-style="{background: getWeight(row, column) ? 'red' :  '' }"
                ng-click="onCellselect(row, column)">
                @{{row}}@{{column}}
            </td>
        </tr>
```

JS:

```
  $http.get("api/getYardGraphDetails")

    .then(function (r) {
        console.log(r.data)

        $scope.weights =r.data

    })

$scope.getWeight = function (row, column) {
    console.log($scope.weights)

        // See if there's a record with the row and column.
        var record = _.find($scope.weights, {
            row: row,
            column: column
        });

        // Was a record found with the row and column?
        if (record) {
            // If so return its weight.
            return record.weight;
        }

};
```

in `$scope.getWeight()` function `$scope.weights` comes from an `$http.get` response. But `console.log($scope.weights)` inside `$scope.getWeight()`  returns undefined

How can i get $scope.weights from `$http.get` for $scope.getWeight() ?

I think i should call `$scope.getWeight()` after `$http.get`returns data from database. As `$http.get` is async it doesn't wait for response and that's my `$scope.weights` doesn't has value in `$scope.getWeight()`.

Comment: Yes, you are right, `$http.get` is async call. So, you will have to call `getWeight` function only after response comes. You can simply use promises for this purpose

Comment: You should check console.log(r) in the api response

Comment: Please read my question, i don't have problem with that. My problem is diffrerent.  @Marcus

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $http.get is invoked on init of the controller, a simple solution would be to guard this with an ng-if. Something like:

```
<tr ng-if="weights" ng-repeat="row in rows">
    <td ng-repeat="column in columns" style="width: 100px; cursor: pointer"
       ng-style="{background: getWeight(row, column) ? 'red' :  '' }"
       ng-click="onCellselect(row, column)">
       @{{row}}@{{column}}
    </td>
```

That way, the function getWeight() will be invoked only after $scope.weights gets populated. If you need to invoke the http more than once, you should invoke getWeights() from the promise resolve instead.

Will this work or am I missing something?

Comment: How can use promise? Can you elaborate, please? @Spitfire

Comment: do you call $http from any other place which might update $scope.weights?

Comment: see my question. i provided js file.

Comment: If the JS provided is all the code there is, then using ng-if will do the trick for you. You can initialize $scope.weights = []; on init and then check ng-if="weights.length>0" on your <tr>. That will work too. Try it.

Answer (score 1):

the thing is getWeight is called before the $http.get has returned.
what I would have done is inside the then function create $scope.weights as and array, somthing like this

```
$http.get("api/getYardGraphDetails")

.then(function (r) {
    console.log(r.data)

    $scope.weights =[]
    for(var weight in r.data){
        $scope.weights[weight.row + "-" + weight.column] = _.find($scope.weights, {
        row: weight.row,
        column: weight.column
    });
    }
})
```

then use it like this

```
ng-style="{background: weights[row + '-' + col]  ? 'red' :  '' }"
```

Comment: Error: [$parse:ueoe]  `<td ng-repeat="column in columns" style="width: 100px; cursor: pointer" ng-style="{background: weights[row + " -"="" +="" column]="" ?="" 'red'="" :="" ''="" }"="" ng-click="onCellselect(row, column)" class="ng-binding ng-scope">`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should familiarize yourself with promises.  You should understand when to use `.then`, how to chain promises and when to use [`$q`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) in AngularJS.

I don't really understand what your question is exactly.  Assume it's "How do I make sure that `getWeight` doesn't have its logic execute until after the `$http` request is done", you can do it like this (untested):

```
var weightsPromise = $http.get("api/getYardGraphDetails")
.then(function (r) {
    console.log(r.data);
    return r.data;
});

$scope.getWeight = function (row, column) {
    return weightsPromise.then(function (weights) { 
        // weights here is r.data from above.
        console.log(weights);

        // See if there's a record with the row and column.
        var record = _.find(weights, {
            row: row,
            column: column
        });

        // Was a record found with the row and column?
        if (record) {
            // If so return its weight.
            return record.weight;
        }
    });
};
```

The only thing is now the API is different. `$scope.getWeight` returns a promise that returns the weight, and doesn't just return the weight anymore.

If this doesn't do what you want, your other option is to wait until the request is finished before calling `$scope.getWeight`.  Spitfire's `ng-if` approach does this.

Comment: @Fawel Can you make a plunker

Comment: I made a live api for you. famousbag.toybiaconstruction.com/api/getYardGraphDetails. I failed to make plnkr with live api as it causes CORS error. Can you test it on your local and then send me? @jared

Comment: @Fawel You can make a .json file in a plunker and perform a `$http.get` request on the .json file as the url.  Alternatively you can use a `fakeHttp` service that replicates the server's functionality if the GET request doesn't always return the same thing like on [my answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44185151/how-to-make-excel-like-cell-in-javascript-or-angularjs-dynamically/44247528#44247528).